# Example for $f$ Lebesgue integrable on $[-n,n]$, but not Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, give an example of $f$ such that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[-n,n]$ for all $n$ and $\int_{-n}^n fd\mu$ converges as $n\rightarrow \infty$, but $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is certainly an interesting problem, but I haven't had any luck to think of an example, any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose any odd, continuous [see note] function that isn't integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

For instance, $f(x) = x$ works.

We have $\int_{-n}^n fd\mu = 0$ for all $n$, which of course converges to $0$, and $\int_\mathbb{R} |f|d\mu = \infty$, so $f$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Note: "Continuous" is a bit stronger than perhaps we want, but it suffices to give plenty of examples.  If you want, however, you can extend the answer by replacing "continuous" with "measurable and bounded on compact sets".

Comment: Oh wow! That is very smart, but I just couldn't figure it out...

Comment: @Felicks It's pretty common to have a blind spot.  Do note I had to update my post from "measurable" to "continuous" to make a general $f$ work.  You could replace "continuous" with "measurable and bounded on compacts" if you want to generalize

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Then $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ converges, but $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}|f(x)|dx$ not.

Comment: Thank you, but why is $\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)|$ related to $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f$?

Comment: It means, that $|f|$ is not Lebesgue integrable, so is not integrable $f$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But what does that say about the problem? And $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{sin\, x}{x}d\mu = \pi$